# How do I set up QtDesigner for a project that has animated elements?

Tags: python, user-interface, qt, animation, pyqt

I'm writing a project to simulate creatures moving around a map.  These can be represented by simple circles, but I need a map/grid and those circles animated on top of the map.

What elements should I use in QtDesigner to set up for this kind of GUI in my project?  I've yet to do anything like this before

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a [Graphics View](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicsview.html) to do it right, but if you don't care about performance, you might be able to get by with just setting the pos on a bunch of buttons to move them around on a widget (without a layout).